# USB Microphone detected but not picking sound in ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 23.04

Hi recently installed ubuntu 23.04, my Maono USB mic detected but Not picking Sound. How to solve this issue.
Thankyou

Got this error

```
[   37.797203] input: DCMT Technology USB Condenser Microphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.3/0003:31B2:0011.0009/input/input31
[   37.854891] hid-generic 0003:31B2:0011.0009: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [DCMT Technology USB Condenser Microphone] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input3
[   37.910261] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[   38.200569] usb 2-1.2: cannot submit urb 0, error -28: not enough bandwidth
```

just found microphone working only in usb3.0 port, not working in any other port, front panel and motherboard usb 2.0 ports

Comment: Finally i decided to Install fresh OS, Now no usb error, but problem is there.